# Gentle introduction to Hilbert modular forms?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

I've been recently wanting to begin learning about Hilbert modular forms, but I haven't found a good set of notes to start from.  I know a little bit about modular forms, the modular curve, oldforms, newforms, that kind of stuff.

Ideally I want to find something which explains things as carefully as Diamond and Shurman's book *A First Course on Modular Forms*.  What are some good references for this topic?

Comment: The 1-2-3 of Modular Forms has a pretty solid introduction, especially if you are already familiar with elliptic modular forms. I don't know of any texts that are quite as detailed as A First Course in Modular Forms, unfortunately.

Comment: This [mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55275/hilbert-modular-forms) is relevant.

Comment: Just a comment, in the (traditional, theta series) proof of the functional equation for Dedekind and Hecke L-functions there are various kind of automorphic forms appearing

Comment: You might like van der Geer's [Hilbert Modular Surfaces](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540176015).